# How to change a direction of lines in Pillow python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a grid, and I made a lines in one way but other way I it doesn't seem to work, I got some weird lines going in other directions. Any idea how to get it right?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

for y in range (-2000, 2000, 200):
    draw.line(((y, 2000), (2000, y)), (0, 0, 0), 20)

img
```

Output produced by code sample

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to draw : `y = -x`, so:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
for x in range (-1000, 1000, 100):
    draw.line(((x,-x),(x+img.size[0], -x+img.size[1])), (0, 0, 0), 20)

img.show()
```

[image]

I used img.size to dynamically choose the second point of the line , you can hardcode it to 2000 `(x+2000,-x+2000)` , If you want to keep it that way